# "Unable to connect to renderer" after upgrade to protractor 4.0.9. Tests won't run. Any ideas as to why?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I had been happily using protractor 3.3.0 with chromedriver 2.21 until Chrome version 54 broke it. I updated to protractor 4.0.9 with chromedriver 2.24 as recommended by the interwebs and now I can't get protractor to run my tests. It looks like it'll start up, flashing a browser window and then throwing this...

Stack trace:

```
[09:51:27] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[09:51:27] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:51:28] E/launcher - session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
[09:51:28] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
    at WebDriverError (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:10)
    at SessionNotCreatedError (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:308:10)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:639:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:538:13)
    at /Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:472:11
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
    at /Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25
    at /Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:329:24)
    at Driver (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:778:38)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:68:26)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:198:43)
    at /Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:277:30
    at _fulfilled (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/Users/gregorybuchanan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[09:51:28] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I can't find anything referencing this problem...Any ideas?

- macOS Sierra
- Chrome 54
- Protractor 4.0.9
- Selenium 2.53.1
- Node 4.2.6

My conf.js file:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  suites: {
    views: './*_view_spec.js',
    forms: './*_form_spec.js',
    active: ['./registration_spec.js', './onboarding_spec.js'],
    all: './*_spec.js',
    current: './registration_spec.js'
  },
  specs: ['./*_spec.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: false
  },
  directConnect: true,
  capabilities: {
    chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--user-data-dir=ProtractorTestProfile','--prompt-for-external-extensions=false', '--load-extension=extension-debug/development/chrome']
          },
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  params: {
    environment: {
      api: 'dev',
      baseUrl: 'http://webapp-dev.xxxxxxx.com/#/'
    }
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
    var disableNgAnimate = function() {
      angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate', function($animate) {
        $animate.enabled(false);
      }]);
    };

    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);

    browser.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
      browser.params.browser = caps.get('browserName');
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure this out and couldn't burn anymore time trying. A complete/fresh install of macOS did the trick.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and it turns out that the problem was with my `/etc/hosts` file. I had

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   hostname
::1             localhost.localdomain   hostname
```

when it was supposed to be

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

so the Selenium server thought that you were connecting to it from a remote address or something and blocked the connection.

That's also probably why a fresh reinstall of macOS fixed the problem for you.

Hopefully this helps somebody looking at this in the future!

Comment: You are a life saver

Comment: Amazing! My `/etc/hosts` file was actually empty, but I pasted this in and it worked like a charm!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How have you updated the chrome driver? By using:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.24 ?
```

I had this exactly same issue and I resolved by downloading the chrome driver version from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/  extracting the file into my selenium folder *(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/)* and removing the old one.

I believe there is some error with updating chrome driver using command lines, see: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/102

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried everything....turns out there was some strange issue deep in the basement of my machine. I did a complete fresh install and now I'm back in business.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and reset the hosts, then clear the socket by using

```
chrome://net-internals/#sockets
```

That would do the trick.

It's not a selenium or a webdriver problem, just some thing to do with the chrome socket/host buffering.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same issue. One day I was running tests just fine, the other day I turned on the IDE, ran the tests again, and it spat out this error. I stumbled upon a solution when I killed Chrome, ChromeDriver, and Eclipse processes, copied a version of Chrome driver that I randomly picked form the repo, then restarted them all and it started working again for some reason. I unfortunately have no idea about the root of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue on `Chrome: Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and `ChromeDriver Version: 2.32`. I just followed these steps and I am able to run my tests successfully

If you are using `browser.manage().window().maximize();` or anything with browser.manage() in your page objects or tests, try to remove them and use the chrome capabilities in protractor.conf.js.

Here is an Example:

```js
capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            // binary: 'PATH/To/your/binary',
            args: [
                '--disable-infobars', "--disable-gpu", "--start-maximized", '--disable-extensions'
            ],
            prefs: {
                // disable chrome's annoying password manager
                'profile.password_manager_enabled': false,
                'credentials_enable_service': false,
                'password_manager_enabled': false
            }
        }
    }
```